# "Too many symbols" with Cocoapods and extension

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ios-app-extension

I've submited an App with a Messages Extension. I'm using Cocoapods for managing library dependencies. Here's the Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
abstract_target 'Common' do
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'MTDates'
    pod 'Mantle'
    pod 'CryptoSwift'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
    pod 'SSZipArchive', '~> 1.0'

    target '<App-Name>' do
    <App-Only pods>
    end
    target '<Messages-Extension>' do
    <Extension-Only pods>
    end
end
```

When submitting to the App Store I got an email saying

> Too many symbol files - These symbols have no corresponding slice in any binary [15C994DA-B600-327E-9B14-57ECDDF741BC.symbols, 1DEFE0F7-B903-3184-B05F-06DCD5D63B37.symbols, 296BC9E7-1425-3A80-839C-E0AC07A69713.symbols, 2F298270-3486-3592-8408-B27B596A6ADD.symbols, 32F52BD4-7315-308F-8A6E-5B747CDFC41B.symbols, 4819548A-DDF4-3640-AEC7-A25886A4881C.symbols, 67919FAF-CEC9-385A-A61A-3C6633A71C8D.symbols, 68FC9F33-96C4-3591-9F82-685841726A27.symbols, 7D9F9F55-EB88-3AEA-9B74-1B73869981F6.symbols, 94A3F51C-0AC8-38BC-BE21-9CF1AC9C6F5E.symbols, A3129167-A114-3A52-8C6D-92AA645DFE1D.symbols, B099BAE2-8DFE-390B-96B1-9D66F804E621.symbols, B5961369-36F6-3170-B419-F633D33540F7.symbols, BA0B4931-4E2A-3617-9429-4C713DAC6796.symbols, CC951B68-E97A-3404-BDFA-58A2941CE4AE.symbols, D11743A3-3EC7-30D2-A167-48E7925CA2DA.symbols, D8C5216A-397C-3104-9D37-42B277C4AE6E.symbols, DE9C3EC5-34AF-3D94-ADEF-3245A5118971.symbols, EF5904E6-7959-3058-8E82-06AEC77FBF1F.symbols, F1790BFF-704A-3280-87A7-EDB08370CC07.symbols]

After using `dwarfdump -u` as stated on some other answers I found out the symbols are from the  pods target (AFNetworking, MTDates, etc). These pods are used from my extension and my App so I thought the proper way of managing them is by creating an abstract target above App and Extension.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I prevent these issues?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Redundant dSYM files are being produced due to improper project settings. In my case, the "project" consists of one major xcproject and several cocoapod projects, and the Build Setting\Valid Architectures setting of the latter one is more extensive than the former. Thus XCode is producing redundant dSYM files for that pod projects and Apple detected those dSYM files is useless because the main project is set to a more constrained level.